# After a template has loaded fully rendered i want an event i can

Tags: angularjs, angular-routing

Quite new to AngularJS and still trying to find my feet.

I'm trying to figure out at some Point when a view completes rendering the template. I have tried just about everything suggestion online, no no avail.

Essentially i want to be able to get a handle on when the template has been fully rendered by angular so then i can call jQuery plugins at that point. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

```
my_app.config(function($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider.
          when('/', {
            templateUrl: '/templates/demo-details',
            controller: 'DemoShowCtrl'
          });
});

<div ng-view onload="alert('finally loaded');" class="container-fluid">

</div>

my_app.controller("DemoShowCtrl", function($scope,$rootScope, Demo) {
        Demo.get({ id: 18875 }, function(data) {
            $scope.deal = data;
        });
        $scope.$on('$viewContentLoaded ', alert('viewContentLoaded'));
        $scope.$on('$routeChangeSuccess ', alert('routeChangeSuccess'));
        $scope.$on('$destroy ', alert('destroy'));

        $rootScope.$on('$viewContentLoaded ', alert('viewContentLoaded'));
        $rootScope.$on('$routeChangeSuccess ', alert('routeChangeSuccess'));
        $rootScope.$on('$destroy ', alert('destroy'));


        //});
    });
```

Comment: no no no, thats not how you use jquery plugins in angular, you use directives for that

Comment: Isn't the `$viewContentLoaded` event want you want?

Answer (score 0):

`viewContentLoaded` is indeed the event that you need, but this is only available using the [angular-ui](http://angular-ui.github.io/) plugin.